# If I am following the Clean Architecture, in which layer should I put the logic for checking if a foreign key exists?

Tags: asp.net, clean-architecture

I am building a web application in .NET Core following the Clean Architecture. I have an use case class for creating an user. Each user has a role which is passed in as an id. The use case will call to the User Repository for creating the user.

Currently, I am using FluentValidation for validating the request object. It is just pure checking such as length, not empty, etc..

My problem is that I don't know where to put the validation logic for validating the existence of the provided role. The validator is currently in the Application layer. I am going with putting the validation logic in the User repository but that doesn't sound right to me.

Do you have any ideas?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should add it in the validator using Fluent Validation. There are options to make custom validator and to make them `async` with Fluent Validation.

Creating a method in the repository for checking for the role is not necessarily wrong. But it should defently be called in validation layer along with other checks like not empty etc. etc.

For performance sake make sure that you call the check once all the other validations have passed.

Comment: If I get you right, then I would create a custom validator for checking the existence of the provided role in the Application layer. But, is it right to allow the Application layer depend on the DB layer? Or should I create an Exist method in the Role Repository interface and then call that inside the custom validator?

Comment: The second option you said. Create that method on the repository and get it from there. After all the "domain layer" contains the interfaces of the repositories. The implementations are what "live" in the data layer. If the application layer had no way to communicate to a data source the clean architecture would not work. The important part is where you keep the interfaces. The domain layer keeps only the data layer interfaces